# Can we test the methods written in Kotlin with Mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mobile-application

Can we test the Mobile Application methods written in Kotlin with Mockito tool?

Have a mobile application which uses the library written in kotlin. Can Mockito supports to test these library methods.

Comment: It would have taken far less time to enter "test kotlin with mockito" in Google than to write this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Mockito can be used with Kotlin.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Couldyou provide a best link which has some basic examples Mockito with Mobile apps. I'm following some sites though.